# Can someone help me on datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui, yii2, jquery-ui-datepicker

I follow all the instruction on how to use [yii2-jui datepicker](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-jui) and also i download the [jquery-ui](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui), i follow all the instruction on how to install and where to put those downloads, after that i try this code

```
<?= $form->field($model,'date')->widget(DatePicker::className(),['clientOptions' => ['defaultDate' => '2014-01-01']]) ?>
```

i also include the `use yii\jui\DatePicker;` but the `DatePicker` doesn't work the ouput is always like `textInput`

looking at my JS errors it appear this:

```
TypeError: jQuery(...).datepicker is not a function
```

I don't know problem, for more vision here is my code :

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
use yii\jui\DatePicker;
?>
<div class="payee">
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'payee_id')->dropDownList(['a' => 'Item A', 'b' => 'Item B', 'c' => 'Item C'] )->label('Payee'); ?> 
        <?= $form->field($model, 'payee_address')->textInput(['style'=>'width: 400px', 'placeholder'=>'Address' ] )->label('Address'); ?> 
        <?= $form->field($model,'date')->widget(DatePicker::className(),['clientOptions' => ['defaultDate' => '2014-01-01']]) ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'payee_number')->textInput(['style'=>'width: 400px', 'placeholder'=>'Disbursement #' ] )->label('Disbursement Number'); ?> 
        <div class="form-group">
            <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
 </div><!-- payee -->
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check your browser console for javascript errors, there will no doubt be at least one. Also: I don't see a `register()`-call to an `AssetBundle` in your code. Usually these kind of widgets have one that should be included in your view so that it can publish the `js` and `css` files to use.

Comment: @Blizz i see an error on my js error , `TypeError: jQuery(...).datepicker is not a function @ http://localhost/yii2_sample1/web/index.php?r=site%2Fpayee:326`

Comment: the assets are being registered in the widget itself, so ignore my remark. Your error does insinuate that somehow it hasn't loaded the associated javascript file though. Are there any 404's in the list of loaded urls?

Comment: @Blizz there's no 404 in the list of loaded urls. i can't move on because of this error :/

Comment: No need to state that again, if you could move on you wouldn't have to ask here, that doesn't change a thing. For some reason the javascript hasn't been loaded, what that reason is is not something we can see based on the information given here. I can't see your screen. Just make sure that it loads jquery-ui.min.js along the way first, we'll see from there.

Comment: is it possible to include the jquery lib in my view , if yes how can i do that.

Comment: This should be done automatically by the `->widget(DatePicker::className())` call, which is why I asked if you could verify that `jquery-ui` and `jquery` are actually loaded.

Comment: If don't know how to verify if `jquery-ui` and `jquery` loaded, can you give idea on how to know if there loaded?

Comment: If you look at the netwerk requests being done (you can do that in most browser consoles) you'll have to find a `jquery.js` (or `jquery.min.js`) and a `jquery-ui.js` (or again: `jquery-ui.min.js`). Or something amongst those lines.

Answer (score 0):

I look at my `jquery-ui`, i there's no `jquery-ui.js`.